# Trouble with Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new to JavaScript and this website, so please bear with me (and my English) I am doing a draft for my HSC project, for this project I am using Google Maps JavaScript API to show the location of an area. I am unable to find the code to disable the sensor, as the old API thing had in it, instead of 'callback', which would disable the user of the website the ability to move the map around. Would anyone here be able to help me with my issue?
The code I am using is the Google's sample code.
(I have not changed the default location to keep some privacy)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
          var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
          }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `map`:

```
draggable: false
```

For example:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8,
    draggable: false
});
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to work. Thank you so much. enjoy your day :)